# Read JSON from Dynamic URL and need to populate in Dot-net Core MVC Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

I have worked on reading 2 Sample Json files and try to populate in dropdownlist  with  values title,type,description,filename,height,width,price,rating

**Json file 1==>**

```
{"title": "Brown eggs",
"type": "dairy",
"description": "Raw organic brown eggs in a basket",
"filename": "0.jpg",
"height": 600,
"width": 400,
"price": 28.1,
"rating": 4}
```

**Json file 2==>**

```
[{
"title": "Brown eggs",
"type": "dairy",
"description": "Raw organic brown eggs in a basket",
"filename": "0.jpg",
"height": 600,
"width": 400,
"price": 28.1,
"rating": 4}]
```

`

` First one works fine with my code below but it's not working for the second one. It gives the error - **Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'**

**HomeController.CS** Code

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> ProductCollectiondict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //dynamic dynObj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{a:1,b:2}");
        // dynamic dynObj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("[{a:1,b:2}]");

        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var jsonUrlProducts = webClient.DownloadString(@"C:\Users\NatarajanS\source\repos\KC_EC_WebSite_1\KC_EC_WebSite_1\wwwroot\lib\JSON\Json_F4.json");
        
        dynamic dynObj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonUrlProducts);
        var jObj1 = (JObject)dynObj1;

        foreach (JToken token in jObj1.Children())
        {
            if (token is JProperty)
            {
                var prop1 = token as JProperty;
                ProductCollectiondict1.Add(prop1.Name, (string)prop1.Value);
            }
        }

        ViewData["selectedProductTextDict1"] = ProductCollectiondict1;
        return View();
    }
```

**Index.cshtml** Code

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlProductByText1",
       new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["selectedProductTextDict1"], "Value", "Key"))
```

Still a long way to go in this task for various dynamic JSON URLs . Please kindly help me guide me soon

Comment: You're probably better off deserializing to a `JContainer` and then work your way through it from there. `JContainer` has two derived types that you should look for: `JArray` and `JObject`. On the other hand, if there's any way you can tell from the URL if you'll get products (array) or object containing projects, you should probably use that rather than using this approach.

Comment: @John I  have followed your approach .    working ; dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{a:1,b:2}");
           but its not working dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("[{a:1,b:2}]");

Comment: @ john - I have posted the working code based on your approach. Please kindly help me soon. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your type `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` is wrong. It should be `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>`. This type looks hectic. I think you can trust dynamic typing and read JSON in a more standard way.

`JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(Text);`

This is stated in the original documentation of newtonsoft. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJson.htm

Comment: `JObject` won't work for the first example.

Comment: If the remaining part of the code is changed, it can work.

Comment: I mean you can't deserialize an array to a `JObject`. That's why you have to use `JContainer` (or `JToken`) and then decide.

Comment: Hm. I don't use c# for a while. I don't know. You might be right